# Location tag not working in Web.Config IIS8

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, forms-authentication, iis-8

We have a website hosted on Windows Server 2012 R2 & IIS8 
It has 1 self-hosted web-service & scripts & images  folders that has resources,.js files & images etc.

**Issue is these /js files & CSS files are not loading on login page which is configured for forms authentication. these js files are giving 404 not found error since everything gets redirected to Login.aspx page first**

Things I have checked already

1. Location tags are present in web.config to bypass forms auth for these sub-folders
2. IUSR & IIS_IUSRS & even 'Everyone' has full rights in IIS on this website
3. This app works on all other hosts & local IIS as well . Only on this server facing this problem.

Please help as its already taking my brains out !

Comment: “This app works on all other hosts & local IIS as well . Only on this serve facing this problem.” You cannot post such a question without any proof. Nobody enjoys guess work.

Comment: Sorry but what is guess work here ? On all other IIS servers & local dev IIS , resources(js files etc) load properly except this one. I have also given things that I have already tried.